# A set that is not recursively enumerable and not (K'≤ A)

Tags: undecidability, semi-decidability

Is there a set A such that it's not recursively enumerable and not(K'≤ A) ?
where K' is complement of K= {n| φ  <sub>n</sub>  (n) halts}

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean by $\le A$? Do you mean $\subseteq A$?

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: if K is ≤ than A it means that A is harder than K. it refers to reduction. @Apass.Jack

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please add it _to the question_. Also, please define what you mean by not$(K'\le A)$. Explain what you mean by $\phi_n$. All readers are not using the same textbook or the same notations as you, even if they are in the same country as you. In fact, many (a majority?) of them are in a different country.

Comment: if you are familiar with the context, the notation is obvious.

Comment: In fact, I am familiar with the context and I knew the question and an answer immediately, whatever the notation means. (There are several inequivalent definitions of reductions, in case you are not aware.) The point is whether the question will be understood readily and accurately by most of interested readers. Your approach indicated you just wanted got your answer right away, which is not wrong in anyway. However, it might not be the best intended question this site is built for.

Comment: Then you could simply provide us with your "immediate" answer instead of complaining about the way i asked the question.

Comment: Sorry, I also want to built this site instead of just helping you alone. Had I answered your question, someone  might comment "Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594)". It is supposed to be your responsibility to clarify the question. It is to your advantage to make the question as detailed and as interesting as possible.

Comment: By the way, even though I can "see" the answer immediately, it may still take a long time for me to write an answer if I write one at all.

Comment: Let me emphasize that I am **helping draw more and better answer**, even though I might not answer at all. I am not "complaining". If you prefer, I can just delete all my comments here.